# Coffeescript ajax failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, coffeescript

I get a coffeescript like this

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.rpt-date > a').click ->
    projectName = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text()
    date = $(this).text()
    urlStr = '/monitor/show?project=' + projectName + '&date=' + date
    alert(urlStr)
    # $.get urlStr, (data) ->
    #   $('#right-column').append("ajax success")
```

and it compile to js as following

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('.rpt-date > a').click(function() {
      var date, projectName, urlStr;
      projectName = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text();
      date = $(this).text();
      urlStr = '/monitor/show?project=' + projectName + '&date=' + date;
      return alert(urlStr);
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

Everything works fine. When I click '.rpt-data > a' tag, there's an alert window popup.

But when I change the coffeescript a little (comment alert, uncomment $.get)

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.rpt-date > a').click ->
    projectName = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text()
    date = $(this).text()
    urlStr = '/monitor/show?project=' + projectName + '&date=' + date
    #alert(urlStr)
    $.get urlStr, (data) ->
      $('#right-column').append("ajax success")
```

It compile to js as following

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('.rpt-date > a').click(function() {
      var date, projectName, urlStr;
      projectName = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text();
      date = $(this).text();
      urlStr = '/monitor/show?project=' + projectName + '&date=' + date;
      return $.get(urlStr, function(data) {
        return $('#right-column').append("ajax success");
      });
    });
  });

}).call(this);
```

It failed to trigger http request to '/monitor/show?xxxxxxx'.

I use chrome developer tool to trace the code and found out `return $.get(urlStr, function(data) {...` doesn't execute. It was jumpped over.

I've googled a lot. Some says `windows end of line` issue, and some says `spaces or tabs` issue. I tried both but it still didn't work.

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: well you do not cancel the click event

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. I'm new to JS and Coffeescript. Follow your instruction, i changed <a href="#"> to <a>, and it worked. Now I know where is wrong. I'll look into the "cancel event" thing and fix it up later. But something weird is, this ajax code works sometimes without canceling the click event. Do you have any ideas why that happen?